# Duda con aplicación para filmoteca Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Me ha surgido una duda de cómo encabezar un pequeño programa que tengo que realizar en Java.

Tenemos que crear una filmoteca, donde tengo una base de datos con un listado de películas, y mediante JFrame, tengo que crear la aplicación de manera, que me aparezcan varias casillas, con el titulo, el genero, duración etc.. y debajo una txtlabel en el cual nos muestre la información.

La aplicación tendrá un botón "siguiente" que al hacer click, nos mostrará la información de la siguiente película.. y mi duda es..

Pensé en crear un bucle que lea todas las películas de la base de datos, de manera que cuando el usuario haga click en el botón, haga una iteración, mostrando la película en los labels.. pero como no se como pausar la ejecución del bucle de manera que solo muestre una.

¿Se os ocurre alguna manera más de hacerlo?

Un saludo!

Comment: Quizás no sea tan pequeño ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al leer de base de datos te devuelve un conjunto no necesitas ningún bucle para leerlas. 
Te devuelve el conjunto de datos completo. cada vez que le des al botón siguiente lo que has de hacer es leer el siguiente registro.

```
 ResultSet rs;
    public void leerPeliculas(){
       Statement s = conexion.createStatement();
       this.rs = s.executeQuery ("select nombre, tiempo from pelicula");
    }
    public void siguiente(){
    if( this.rs.next())
    {
        this.lb_nombre.setText(this.rs.getString(0));
        this.lb_tiempo.setText(this.rs.getString(1));
    }
```

es un pequeño ejemplo a groso modo. espero que te sirva.